# Removing Style tag from variable with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a variable with lot of html and inline `style` tags. I want to remove all `style` tags from this html variable.
I have already used this but it is returning an object and I am not able to get all html from this object. I think it only works with single html element. But i have lot of paragraphs and spans in this html.

```
jQuery(content).removeAttr('style');
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What does `content` look like? Your above code will work assuming it is an HTMLElement.

Comment: jQuery always return with jQuery object, if you pass an html string to it it is parse it to dom object. You can do: `jQuery(content).removeAttr('style').prop('outerHTML');` to get the html code back;

Comment: How are these style attributes ending up in your markup in the first place?  Just stop adding them?

Comment: content variable have some paragraphs and spans that have style tags and i want to remove these style tags from this variable.

Comment: once you parse it into HTML you should be able to use js methods on that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var content = `
<div style="float:left;width:75%;padding-left:30px;">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type your Search..." style="width:95%;height:84px;border:solid 0px #fff;background-color:#fff;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size:30px;font-weight:300;text-transform: uppercase;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);">
</div> 
<div style="padding:40px 10px 0 0;">
  <div class="hide_1024">PRESS ENTER</div><div class="show_1024">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="closeDark" onclick="closeSearch();"></div>
</div> 
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
`;


content = jQuery('<div>' + content + '</div>').find('*').removeAttr('style').end().html();

console.log(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This code is working for me. Thank you so much for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ALL selector

```
jQuery('*').removeAttr('style');
```

https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment here is the working snippet, I hope it is helps:

```js
var html = '<div><p style="a"></p><p style="a"></p><p style="a"></p><p style="a"></p><p style="a"></p></div>';

var $html = $(html);
$html.find('*').removeAttr('style');

console.log("In:  ", html);
console.log("Out: ", $html.prop('outerHTML'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to remove the styles off an element and all its children? You can do it simply with a recursive function like so. No need for jquery.

```
// Recursively remove styles from a base element.
// Depth first.
function clearStyles(element) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.childElementCount; i++) {
    clearStyles(element.children[i]);
  };
  element.style = '';
}

clearStyles(document.getElementById(id));
```